# convert SOAP to REST and return many records from a function

Tags: vb.net, rest, wcf, soap

Convert working SOAP WCF to REST and still use Function that reads and returns the values I need.

ActiveCallSevice reads entity to return several records using SOAP in VB.  How can I code it to return all the records when changing to REST? I have tried many different versions of the uriTemplate but nothing is working. I basically should read a view and return the data without getting any parms from uri.  I used good example from [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/590627/Converting-SOAP-based-WCF-Service-to-RESTful-Desig), but that one is manually coding value returned from looping and I have a Function that reads and returns the values I need.

My IActiveCalls.vb code current on WebGet line - error states - Constant expression is required.    C:\inetpub\VS2013\wcfWazeP1\IActiveCalls.vb 10  13  WcfWazeP1.

```
Public Interface IActiveCalls

Property UriTemplate As String

<WebGet(UriTemplate = "Function GetWazeCalls() As List(Of DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents)")>
<OperationContract()>
Function GetWazeCalls() As List(Of DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents)

Implements IActiveCalls
Dim dbP1RDW As New ReportingDWEntities

Public Function GetWazeCalls() As List(Of DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents) Implements IActiveCalls.GetWazeCalls
    Return dbP1RDW.DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents.OrderBy(Function(o) o.IncidentDate).ToList()
End Function

<DataContract()>
Public Class ActiveCalls

End Class
```

My ActiveCalls.vb code on Implement line – error states -Class 'ActiveCallsService' must implement 'Property UriTemplate As String' for interface 'IActiveCalls'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers.    C:\inetpub\VS2013\wcfWazeP1\ActiveCalls.vb  9   16  WcfWazeP1.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.Text

Public Class ActiveCallsService
    Implements IActiveCalls
    Dim dbP1RDW As New ReportingDWEntities

    Public Function GetWazeCalls() As List(Of DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents) Implements IActiveCalls.GetWazeCalls
        Return dbP1RDW.DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents.OrderBy(Function(o) o.IncidentDate).ToList()
    End Function
End Class
```

12/07/2017 Thanks GMan80013, After changes. Still have errors that prevent it from running.  I tried several placements of the UriTemplate declaration with no luck.  How important is the name of the UriTemplate? Could I call it anything, or should it reference the ActiveCallsService? Sorry to be so uninformed. 
ActiveCalls.vb two errors
1- Field or property 'UriTemplate' is not found.    C:\inetpub\VS2013\wcfWazeP1\IActiveCalls.vbWcfWazeP1 
2- 'WebGetAttribute' cannot be used as an attribute because it does not inherit from 'System.Attribute'.    C:\inetpub\VS2013\wcfWazeP1\IActiveCalls.vb
    
    Public Interface IActiveCalls

```
    Property UriTemplate As String

    <WebGet(UriTemplate:="currentSOTrafficeIncidents")>
    <OperationContract()>
    Function GetWazeCalls() As List(Of DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents)

End Interface
```

ActiveCalls.vb – I added the Public Property UriTemplate and no errors here
    Imports System
    Imports System.Collections.Generic
    Imports System.Linq
    Imports System.Runtime.Serialization
    Imports System.ServiceModel
    Imports System.Text

```
Public Class ActiveCallsService
    Implements IActiveCalls
    Dim dbP1RDW As New ReportingDWEntities
    Public Property UriTemplate As String Implements IActiveCalls.UriTemplate

    Public Function GetWazeCalls() As List(Of DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents) 
    Implements IActiveCalls.GetWazeCalls
    Return dbP1RDW.DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents.OrderBy(Function(o) 
o.IncidentDate).ToList()
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

1) The URI Template value is meant to represent the part of the URL after the host name.  If your site address is http://www.myhouse.com/ and you want clients to get all records with this address http://www.myhouse.com/currentSOTrafficIncidents Then "currentSOTrafficIncidents" is the URI Template.  Also, possibly the cause of the error, be sure after `UriTemplate` you have `:=` not just `=`.  This is required in vb any time you are specifying the parameter name.

```
<WebGet(UriTemplate:= "currentSOTrafficIncidents")>
<OperationContract()>
Function GetWazeCalls() As List(Of DIT_CurrentSOTrafficIncidents)
```

2) In your interface you declared `Property UriTemplate As String` and this public property is missing from the ActiveCalls.vb class.  I don't think you need this, however and could remove it from the IActiveCalls class.  If you really want to keep it there, correct the error by adding this to ActiveCalls.vb.

```
Public Property UriTemplate As String Implements IActiveCalls.UriTemplate
```

Comment: 12/07/2017 Thanks GMan80013, After changes. Still have errors that prevent it from running, I edited my question with an update.